# How to get the transformed XML from Saxon 10.6 as a string

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon, xslt-3.0

I am using below code for transforming the XML based on XSLT using Saxon 10.6. I could get the transformed XML in file. But I need the transformed XML assigned to a string. Kindly help to achieve this.

```
Source xslt = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXSLT));
Source xml = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXML));
Processor processor = new Processor(false);
XsltCompiler compiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
XsltExecutable stylesheet = compiler.compile(xslt);
Serializer out = processor.newSerializer(new File("C:/Users/Abc/books.xml"));
out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.METHOD, "xml");
out.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
Xslt30Transformer transformer = stylesheet.load30();
transformer.transform(xml,out);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `processor.newSerializer(java.io.Writer writer)` using a java.io.StringWriter.